# Nginx is configured for SSL, configuration?

Tags: ssl, nginx, client-certificates

I have Nginx configured with SSL.  It requests certificates as users access the site, this is working fine.  If I wanted a particular page of my site to be accessible without requiring the certificate, how can that be accomplished?  An important factor to me is keeping all other pages requiring the certificate, and only one page as not requiring the certificate.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You will always need a certificate to serve any url as https. What you can do instead is allows one specific URL to be served as http, and have any other redirect to its https analog

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy with `nginx`. You can set `ssl_verify_client optional;`, but then you will need to check the `$ssl_client_verify` variable manually.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_verify_client) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx finds the longest matching location so you can specify your exception(s) and then pass all other traffic to https, like so:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    location /exception/ {  # redirect https requests to http server
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    # ...
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {  # the default location redirects to https
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    location /exception/ {}  # do not redirect requests
    # ...
}
```

I hope this is helpful.